# GridBagLayout get position of a component

Tags: java, image, swing, background

How can I get the position or width and height of a component in a GridBagLayout so I can paint an image behind it for example.
`component.getWidth()`, `component.getHeight()`,`component.getBound()` all retrieve 0.

Comment: *"get the position or width and height of a component in a GridBagLayout so I can paint an image behind it"*  This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  The better approach is to extend a container (e.g. a `JPanel`) then override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method to call the super method (to paint the BG and components) and paint the image.

Comment: *"How can I get a method to execute when the window is fully loaded?"*  `paintComponent(Graphics)` fulfills that description.  It is also called whenever the API determines it is necessary. in order to repaint the window after any number of possible changes or updates.  *"(WTE) what if I need the dimensions later"*  You keep slipping into 'XY Problem' mode.  Did you read the information at the link?  After you've done that, you might understand when I ask.  **Why would you need that information (*ever*)?**

Comment: @AndrewThompson- I don't want to repaint the whole thing :( . And you are right I fell in a XY problem.